# Duvida Jboss Data Virtualization

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Boa noite, estou com um projeto onde tenho que consumir tabelas geradas em formato estrela, para uso de BI, a empresa comprou uma ferramenta paga, mas não quer gasta muito com licenças. Portanto uma interface para usuário terá que ser criada, so que utilizar jdbc para carregar essa informação a cada consulta ficaria muito pesado ja que tem consultas que levam mais de 2 minutos para retornar o resultado.

Gostaria de saber se o **JBoss Data Virtualization** ou o **JBoss Data Grid** atenderiam o meu proposito.

Li que ele realiza consultas e armazena essas informações em um banco virtualizado, assim podendo ser consumido, sem precisar realizar novas consultas, fora o poder de relacionar os dados com outras fontes como WS ou outros bancos.

Queria saber se é isso mesmo ou a cada vez que consumo uma tabela virtualizada pelo *JDV* é gerado uma nova consulta.
Gostaria de saber também se o consumo dessas informações é um processo "fácil".

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Acabamos usando Data Grid amigo.

Comment: Que bom joão, então você poderia tentar criar uma resposta para sua pergunta, pois assim você não deixa sua pergunta sem reposta, e ainda ajuda outras pessoas.

Comment: Vou responder sim.